# How to mock ServletContext to access WAR resources in unit test?

Tags: java, unit-testing, servlets, war, freemarker

I have a Jetty web-app that is getting packaged and deployed as a .war via Maven. I am using Apache Freemarker as part of the application to process and create documents. That means I need to be able to load template files that are packaged up in the WAR. Freemarker provides a method for doing this (`Configuration.setServletContextForTemplateLoading`), but it requires passing in an instance of `ServletContext` as a parameter. Easy enough in the production code, but I'm a bit stuck when it comes to my unit tests. I don't have a ServletContext there, so how do I get an instance to pass to Freemarker? Is there a way to do this with mocking? I tried using `MockServletContext` from Spring, but I couldn't get it to work. I'm not even sure if I can use that library without the rest of the Spring Framework.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

For testing purpose it's probably the best to use `MockServletContext`, because then your test is closer to the production system. If that's too problematic for some reason, there's an other way, assuming it's your code that calls `setServletContextForTemplateLoading`. `configuration.setServletContextForTemplateLoading(servletContext)` is just a convenience method for `configuration.setTemplateLoader(new WebappTemplateLoader(servletContext))`. So, where your code calls `setServletContextForTemplateLoading`, you could call `setTemplateLoader` instead, and then expose the `TemplateLoader` as a bean that's a `WebappTemplateLoader` in production, but is replaced with a `ClassTemplateLoader` instance during testing. (Actually, maybe you can use `ClassTemplateLoader` both in production and testing.)

Comment: Do you know of a good example or tutorial for MockServletContext? It does seem to offer what I want, but every bit of information I found seemed to assume use of the full Spring framework. I just want to mock my context; I don't need all the other baggage.

Comment: @pbuchheit I don't know any specifics, but it's part of Spring Test, so, you will need Spring as dependency for it. I assumed you project uses Spring anyway, but if not... maybe other mocks/dummies exist.